# Want to output column values against a certain column value

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to output bid_amount column values given luggage_id.
Below is the screenshot.
With reference to the screenshots e.g if luggage_id is 123561 i want to get only the bid_amounts 255,25 and 88.

[image]

**My Controller**

```
public function bid(){

                            $this->load->database();  
                            $this->load->model('Truckeraccount_model');
                            $data['h']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->loads();  
                            redirect('truckeraccount_ctrl/');

}
```

**My Model**

```
public function loads()  {  

                            $luggage_id = $this->session->userdata('luggage_id'); 
                            $this->db->select('*');
                            $this->db->from('bids');
                            $this->db->where('luggage_id', $luggage_id); 
                            $query = $this->db->get('bids');
                            return $query; 
}
```

**My View**

```
<?php

               foreach ($h->result() as $row)  
 {
?>   
Luggage: <?php echo $row->luggage_id;?><br>
Bids: $<?php echo $row->bid_amount;?>

<?php } ?>
```

The data is being outputed as separate rows.

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: Am trying to get an array of values of the column bid_amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

**In Controller**

```
public function bid(){

    $this->load->database();  
    $this->load->model('Truckeraccount_model');
    $data['bids']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->loads();  

    # remove below and load view
    //redirect('truckeraccount_ctrl/');

    $this->load->view('name', $data);

}
```

**In Model**

```
public function loads()  {  

    $luggage_id = $this->session->userdata('luggage_id'); 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bids');
    $this->db->where('luggage_id', $luggage_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get('bids');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; 
}
```

**In View**

```
foreach ($bids as $bid) {
    echo "Luggage ".$bid['luggage_id'];
    echo "Bids ".$bid['bid_amount']; ;
}
```

Comment: Hey Abdul. Am getting the error below. trying to go around it.     A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mala/application/views/truckers/truckeraccount_view.php on line 290
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: truckers/truckeraccount_view.php

Line Number: 290      line 290 is  <?php echo "Bids ".$bid['bid_amount']; ?>

Comment: what is in line 290 ??

Comment: Line 290 is  <?php echo "Bids ".$bid['bid_amount']; ?>

Comment: `print_r($bids)` in view and post data. Be quick

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Managed to sort it out.  had written   echo "Luggage ".$bid->truckerid; instead of echo "Truckerid ".$bid['truckerid'];   Thank you very much

Comment: @Cooper happy to help ;)